# What is emacs.superfaq.net thing?

Tags: discussion

Here is what I have found with help of my search engine:

http://emacs.superfaq.net/

Is it legal? They even copy StackExchange logo. Also, users may try to login into this thing by mistake revealing their passwords, etc.

Should this be reported or something?

Comment: It also appears (just from looking at the URL, not from actually using it) that after logging in, you get redirected to `emacs.stackexchange.com`. This definitely looks fishy.

Comment: By contrast meta.emacs.stackexchange.com seems to not be there.

Comment: Yes it should: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/266014

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it was, it seems to be gone now.  The site resolves, but attempting to visit it gets me a "502 Bad Gateway" nginx server error.